# Subtitles 3 lines to 2 lines

Tags: television, subtitle

I've got subtitles that are 3 lines long. 
The third line falls off when I'm watching it on tv. 
Is there some tool that can fix 3 lined subtitles to all 2 lines?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are asking in the right forum but try subtitle workshop:

http://www.urusoft.net/products.php?cat=sw